# Como inserir runtime permission em uma webview que obtém a localização do usuário?

Tags: android, webview, permissões, runtime, android-permission

Então.. Estou começando a criar uma *webview* e o site que estou me baseando tem uma opção de obter as coordenadas de um certo local, no site isso funciona perfeitamente, mas quando coloco no *APP* ele abre o *Google maps* (que é o que eu quero) só que ele não consegue resolver a localização atual do usuário para definir a rota, etc.

**Aparece a mensagem**:

> "O Google Maps não detectou sua localização exata".

Eu dei uma pesquisada e penso que é só adicionar uma *runtime permission* quando o *APP* abrir, dizendo que preciso acessar a localização do usuário, mas como sou iniciante não tenho certeza.

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //chamada para webview
    private WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //conditional to check network
        if(!isConnected(MainActivity.this)) buildDialog(MainActivity.this).show();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Bem vindo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setFocusable(true);
        wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        //Carregar URL
        wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        
        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }

    //Check INTERNET connectivity
    public boolean isConnected(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if((mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting())) return true;
            else return false;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public AlertDialog.Builder buildDialog(Context c) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setTitle("Sem conexão de Internet");
        builder.setMessage("Ative os Dados móveis ou acesse a rede WIFI para navegar. Pressione Ok para sair.");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                finish();
            }
        });

        return builder;
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                view.reload();
                return true;
            }

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch (keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(wv.canGoBack()){
                        wv.goBack();
                    }
                    else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: O que abre é a página do Google Maps na sua webview ou é o app Google Maps instalado no dispositivo?

Comment: A página do Google Maps dentro da webview, mas, qualquer uma das 2 opções é válida no meu caso. Só quero que funcione... Tanto faz se abrir no app do Google Maps instalado ou dentro da webview.